# Seeding nested models, duplicate key error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two associated models

Workout:

```
has_many :exercises, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :exercises, 
                              :reject_if => :all_blank,
                              :allow_destroy => true
```

Exercises:

```
belongs_to :workout
```

The Workout controller has the following params:

```
params.require(:workout).permit(:name, exercises_attributes: [:id,:name,:reps,:sets,:weight])
```

And here is my seed.rb file

```
5.times do |i|
  Workout.create(name: i, exercises_attributes: [ 
                                              name: 'Bench Press',
                                              reps: 5, 
                                              sets: 5, 
                                              weight: 200.0],
                      exercises_attributes: [ 
                                              name: 'Squat',
                                              reps: 5, 
                                              sets: 5, 
                                              weight: 100.0])
end
```

When I run rake db:reset I get the following error:

```
~/db/seeds.rb:14: warning: duplicated key at line 19 ignored: :exercises_attributes
```

The result is the Squat exercise gets added and the Bench Press exercise gets ignored. Any idea how I can resolve this so that both are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the duplicate key error because you are specifying it twice in your `Workout.create` call.

Try only sending it once, but with an array of hashes, so that you fit both exercises into the same array:

```
5.times do |i|
  Workout.create(name: i, exercises_attributes: [ 
    {
      name: 'Bench Press',
      reps: 5, 
      sets: 5, 
      weight: 200.0
    },
    {
      name: 'Squat',
      reps: 5, 
      sets: 5, 
      weight: 100.0
    }]
  )
end
```